# Запрос T-SQL из PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Вопрос.

Хочу протестировать список соединений. Если какой-то хост недоступен, добавить его имя и время опроса в базу:

```
$query = "merge into tgt
            using (select '$h' as Server '$start' as Start from t1) src
            on (tgt.Server = src.Server)
            when  not matched then insert(Server, Start) values(src.Server, src.Start);"
```

А система ругается:
`Invoke-Sqlcmd : Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "2022.11.16 11:01:53".` Собственно, это дата. Если просто вставить данные:

```
"Insert into t1 (Server, Start) Values ('$h', '$start') Where not exists (Select * from t1 Where Server like '$h');"
```

То все ОК. Что у меня не так в MERGE?

Не удалось сюда добавить переменные, сайт ругается на неправильный код. В общем,

$start = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss')
$h = 'Server'

Comment: select '$h' as Server '$start' <- тут запятой не хватает

Comment: так?  using (select '$h' as Server, '$start' as Start from t1) src

Comment: Ну да - Вы протестируйте и увидите